# Can Google Docs show hidden characters?

Tags: google-docs

Is it possible to show hidden characters on a Google Doc? If not, how does one request such a feature?

Answer (score 8):

Currently, no. [Source](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/kTwrkQliNPM).

[This seems to be the place](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topicsearchin/drive/feature$20request) to send Google your feedback with regards to Google Drive. [Here is a filtered view](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topicsearchin/docs/category$3A(idea)$20is$3Afirstpost%7Csort:relevance) of the Google Docs help page which you may want to try posting your feedback in as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a way. [Show](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/show/cookfoficdecobaeegihlmciepcgpplm) is an extension that displays non-printable characters within a Google Docs document.

Comment: If you are affiliated with the creator of the extension, you should disclose it.

Comment: What about Sebastien's comment makes you think he's affiliated with the creator???

Answer (score 1):

Found in a more recent forum that there's an add-on called [Show](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/show/cookfoficdecobaeegihlmciepcgpplm) that works, so you can see non-printable characters in your Google Doc.